# If $\tan\left(22 \frac{1}{2}^\circ\right)=\sqrt2 -1$, prove $\tan\left(11 \frac{1}{4}^\circ\right)=\sqrt{4+2\sqrt2} -\sqrt2 -1$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\tan\left(22 \frac{1}{2}^\circ\right)=\sqrt2 -1$, then prove that $$\tan\left(11 \frac{1}{4}^\circ\right)=\sqrt{4+2\sqrt2}    -\sqrt2   -1$$

please help me I could not even get to the first step..

Comment: As $11 \frac 14$ is half of $22 \frac12$, half-angle identities seem like a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\tan 2\alpha = \frac{2\tan \alpha}{1 -\tan^2\alpha}$$
Let $\alpha=11\frac1{4}$ and $\tan \alpha =x$, then
$$\sqrt2 -1=\frac {2x}{1-x^2}$$
$$x=...$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\tan(2x)=\frac{\sin(2x)}{\cos(2x)}=\frac{2\sin x \cos x}{\cos^2 x -\sin^2 x} =\frac{2 \tan x}{1- \tan^2 x}$$